# Why does my function not work if I use recursion inside the if statement

Tags: python, recursion

I was trying to create a function that returns a list without any repetition using recursion, but I found something intriguing.

When I write the code like this:

```
def norep(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return xs
    if xs[0] in norep(xs[1:]):
        return xs[1:]
    else:
        return xs


l = norep([1, 2, 33, 4, 5, 2, 1, 24, 34, 2, 3, 5])
print(l)
```

the code returns this:

```
[2, 33, 4, 5, 2, 1, 24, 34, 2, 3, 5]
```

When I write it like this:

```
def norep(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return xs
    if xs[0] in xs[1:]:
        return norep(xs[1:])
    else:
        return [xs[0]] + norep(xs[1:])


l = norep([1, 2, 33, 4, 5, 2, 1, 24, 34, 2, 3, 5])
print(l)
```

it returns the expected output:

```
[33, 4, 1, 24, 34, 2, 3, 5]
```

Why doesn't the first code work, but the second one does?

Comment: In the first example you are never actually returning the result of any recursion. You either return `xs[1:]` or `xs`. In the example given you return `xs[1:]`, which is exactly there result you are seeing.

Comment: Can you explain how you thought the first example was recursive?  Because it isn't.

Comment: To be fair @JohnGordon the first example _does_ recurse. The function is called 13 times — it just throws away the result of the recursion.

Comment: Why would you expect the first to work? It's totally different than the second one. It can only ever return one of three things to the initial caller: the input itself or the input with the first element removed. That's it. Everything the recursion returns is discarded, only used for comparison purposes but not returned. On the other hand, the second one actually returns the sub-inputs back up the call stack, building up a list item by item with concatenation. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code:

```
    if xs[0] in xs[1:]:
        return norep(xs[1:])
```

Does the following:

- evaluate `xs[0] in xs[1:]`
- to do so, it evaluates `xs[0]` (some value), evaluates `xs[1:]` (some other value), and the resulting value of the evaluation is a boolean representing whether the first value is in the second value (however that's defined for those values).
- if the result of the evaluation is `True`, runs the next line.
- the next line evaluates `norep(xs[1:])` and will return the outcome as the return value of the function
- to do so, it evaluates `xs[1:]`, and passes the result to `norep()` as the first argument.

So, if `xs[0] in xs[1:]`, the return value of the recursive call will be returned.

However, this bit of code:

```
    if xs[0] in norep(xs[1:]):
        return xs[1:]
```

Does the following:

- evaluate `xs[0] in norep(xs[1:])`
- to do so, it evaluates `xs[0]` (some value), then evaluates `norep(xs[1:])` etc.
- however, evaluating `norep(xs[1:])` means it evaluates `xs[1:]`, and passes the result to `norep()` as the first argument
- if `xs[0]` is in the return value of that function call, runs the next line
- that simply returns the value of `xs[1:]`.

So, in both cases, the function is called recursively. But in the first example, the return value of the recursive call is returned. In the second example, the return value is always `xs[1:]`.

In the `else` part, `xs` is returned, so no return value of the second example's function ever includes the return value of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to do it in a much simpler way, you can just cast the list to a set and then back to a list like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 33, 4, 5, 2, 1, 24, 34, 2, 3, 5]
l = list(set(l))
# Returns [1, 2, 33, 4, 5, 34, 3, 24]
```

Keep in mind that sets are **unordered**, which means that the output might differ for the exact same input. If that's a problem, you can just `l.sort()`.